# QWidget::insertAction Attempt to insert null action at runtime

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

So, I'm trying to run my spreadsheet application in QT Creator and it compiles without errors, but when I try to run the application I get the following error `QWidget::insertAction Attempt to insert null action`. The problem is that I have no idea where the issue is coming from... The error is not appearing in the error section of QT Creator but in the little terminal created when running programs.

I have a `createActions()` function that initializes all the actions initilized in the header, maybe is coming from there?

The actions in the private part of the header look like this:

```
QAction *newAction;
    QAction *openAction;
    QAction *aboutQtAction;

    QAction *closeAction;
    QAction *exitAction;
    QAction *selectAllAction;
    QAction *showGridAction;
    QAction *saveAction;
    QAction *saveAsAction;
    QAction *cutAction;
    QAction *copyAction;
    QAction *pasteAction;
    QAction *deleteAction;
    QAction *selectRowAction;
    QAction *selectColumnAction;
    QAction *findAction;
    QAction *goToCellAction;
    QAction *recalculateAction;
    QAction *sortAction;
    QAction *autoRecalcAction;
    QAction *aboutAction;
```

Here's the function:

```
void MainWindow::createActions()
{
  newAction = new QAction(tr("&New"), this);
  newAction->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/avatar.jpeg"));
  newAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::New);
  newAction->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new spreadsheet file"));
  connect(newAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newFile()));

  for (int i = 0; i < MaxRecentFiles; ++i) {
    recentFileActions[i] = new QAction(this);
    recentFileActions[i]->setVisible(false);
    connect(recentFileActions[i], SIGNAL(triggered()),this, SLOT(openRecentFile()));
  }

  closeAction = new QAction(tr("&Close"), this);
  closeAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Close);
  closeAction->setStatusTip(tr("Close this window"));
  connect(closeAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));

  exitAction = new QAction(tr("E&xit"), this);
  exitAction->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+Q"));
  exitAction->setStatusTip(tr("Exit the application"));
  connect(exitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()),
        qApp, SLOT(closeAllWindows()));
  selectAllAction = new QAction(tr("&All"), this);
  selectAllAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::SelectAll);
  selectAllAction->setStatusTip(tr("Select all the cells in the "
                                    "spreadsheet"));
  connect(selectAllAction, SIGNAL(triggered()),
  spreadsheet, SLOT(selectAll()));

  showGridAction = new QAction(tr("&Show Grid"), this);
  showGridAction->setCheckable(true);
  showGridAction->setChecked(spreadsheet->showGrid());
  showGridAction->setStatusTip(tr("Show or hide the spreadsheet's "
                                  "grid"));
  connect(showGridAction, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),
  spreadsheet, SLOT(setShowGrid(bool)));

  aboutQtAction = new QAction(tr("About &Qt"), this);
  aboutQtAction->setStatusTip(tr("Show the Qt library's About box"));
  connect(aboutQtAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(aboutQt()));
  }
```

These actions, after being created, are added to the menus in the `createMenus()` function:

```
void MainWindow::createMenus(){
fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
fileMenu->addAction(newAction);
fileMenu->addAction(openAction);
fileMenu->addAction(saveAction);
fileMenu->addAction(saveAsAction);

separatorAction = fileMenu->addSeparator();
for (int i = 0; i < MaxRecentFiles; ++i)
    fileMenu->addAction(recentFileActions[i]);

fileMenu->addSeparator();
fileMenu->addAction(exitAction);
...
```

Someone has any idea where this error is coming from?

Thanks!
Axel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `createActions()`, you don't appear to be initializing `openAction`, `saveAction`, or `saveAsAction` - which you then insert into your menu.  I'd guess that's the problem, unless you just didn't include the code initializing those particular actions.

Comment: My bad, the actions are initialized in the header, ill add the relevant part.

Comment: @Axel The stuff you just added - the pointers are *defined* in the header... where do you do `saveAction = new QAction()`? That's when they get *created*

Comment: Oh, just realized that some action were never implemented, that's funny because I tough those kind of errors were going to pop in while compiling as error. So I'm kinda surprised they didn't show as errors in the error output panel of QTCreator o.o

Comment: @Axel Don't add the actions unless you've created them with `new` - as I said in the answer, I suspect that will solve your problem.